# Imagemagic: How to create one image on another image with first image as background

Tags: image, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have two image files. I have a image where text is written on a white background. The second image is a prescription and i want to merge the second image on first image with first image set as background.

**First Image**

[image]

**Second Image**
[image]

When i use below command i get below image

```
composite -geometry +100+20 firstImg.jpg secondImg.jpg finalImg.jpg
```

**finalImage**
[image]

I want the text in the second image to be merged to the first image. I am new to image magic and is stuck with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to use API or command line? which language do you work with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
convert prescription.jpg \
 \( words.jpg -resize 300x -fuzz 10% -transparent white \) \
 -gravity center -geometry +0+80 -composite result.jpg
```

[image]

First I load the prescription template as a background, then I load and resize the words to the correct width, and then make the white (+/- 10%) areas transparent and overlay that onto the middle (`-gravity center`) with a small geometry offset to move it down  little.

I hope you are not being naughty.

Comment: That was my first thoughts Mark. Why would somebody want to write what looks like a prescription onto a blank form?

Comment: @Bonzo I am working on a prototype which can be used for digitizing prescriptions. Added some sample images so that you guys would understand my use case :).

Answer (score 0):

Use [`-compose Multiply`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#compose) to drop white from second image.

```
composite -geometry +100+20 firstImg.jpg secondImg.jpg  -compose Multiply  finalImg.jpg
```